# karbonn A21 is not showing as AVD?

Tags: android

I am writing very simple android program in eclipse but when i want to run that program in my android phone(karbonn A21 with android version 4.0.4) is not shown as AVD.Since the USB debugging is also checked.And Unknown sources is also checked.

Any ideas??

Thanks for your time.

Comment: have you installed the device driver from karbonn site..?

Comment: I tried to install driver using moborobo but it cannot find any driver.

Comment: can you try downloading driver or pc suit from here http://xperiahtcrootingrom.com/karbonn-a21-usb-drivers/

Comment: I downloaded USB driver as you recomended and installed it.At the begining of installation,this message was shown "fail to install driver for windows".Since i am using windows 8.1.